# ubuntu 12.10 update manager fail to fetch with 404 errors

Tags: ubuntu

I keep getting 404 errors when I try run the software updater. The update manager errors with

```
W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/lkjoel/fix404/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/lkjoel/fix404/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
, E:Some
```

`index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

I tried apt-get clean, apt-get update. Can anyone suggest something else to try?

I'm using Ubuntu version 12.10 and I'm trying to upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, better suited for http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try Y PPA Manager - is a tool for easily searching for packages in Ubuntu PPAs as well as perform various PPA actions: add, remove, purge, backup PPAs and more. The application integrates with Unity by using quicklists and an optional appindicator.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

Comment: The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.